# SoapConnection api vs URLConnection api

Tags: java, groovy, http-headers

I am passing the same soap request via `HttpsUrlConnection` and by the default          `SoapConnection.connect()`.

However, the `HttpsUrlConnection` crashes with HTTP response 415 and/or 500. But, `SoapConnection.connect()` runs fine. Does the error code indicate a problem with the request or the response?

I am building httpsUrlConnection:

```
     conn = (HttpsURLConnection)endpoint.openConnection()
     conn.setRequestMethod("GET")
     conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction",endpoint)
     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml")
     conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/xml")
     conn.setDoOutput(true)
     conn.connect()
```

Is this the right setup?

Thanks